# Is $K[X]/(X^2)$ local if $K$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, localization

What I have so far is that since $K$ is a field, $K[X]$ is an integral domain and since $X^2$ is not irreducible, it is not a prime element, so $(X^2)$ is not a prime ideal, which means that $K[X]/(X^2)$ is not an integral domain. Is there a relation between integral domains and local rings (rings with exactly one maximal ideal) that can help me to conclude whether $K[X]/(X^2)$ is local or not?

Comment: This ring has only three ideals : $\{0\}, (X)$ and the ring itself. Only one is maximal.

Comment: Modulo multiplication by a nonzero scalar, the only elements in your ring are $0, 1$, and $X - a$ for $a\in k$. What ideals do they generate?

Comment: Why only $0,1,X-a$ and not $X$ ? If $K=\mathbb{F}_2$, then the elements are $0,1,x,x+1$, am I right?

Comment: $X=X-0$ it is not forgotten...

Comment: What difficulty did you find when you tried to see if the ring was local?

Comment: thank you for your comments. As stated in the question I was thinking of a more general argument and I did not realize that the computations can be done so explicitely, but now it seems clear.

Comment: the ideal generated by 1 is the ring itself and the ideal generated by x-a is also the ring itself so the only maximal ideal is (x)